# Handling the export in eclipse thru a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have a java application that have different settings and dependency versions depending on the company branch it is install in.

So what I did is to create a plugin that create an item in the right click context menu of the project in eclipse to make these changes.

However I am wondering if its possible to catch the OnExport event of eclispe (if it exists) and do this automatically everytime the solution is exported.

Would this be possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, the Eclipse way to do this would be to write a Builder and add it to the project; then the settings file would be rebuilt whenever it's appropriate, making an up-to-date version always available to export.  [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) is a good place to start learning about how to do this.

Comment: Could you show me a small example please or a link to a resource?

Comment: Click on "Here" in my solution above -- it's a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Ahh, excellent, thanks a lot, Its much less of a hassle then using a plugin.